# App_Browser file changes not being picked up by ASP.Net app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, application-pool

I recently deployed a browser file called 'BrowserFile.browser' under App_Browsers folder. Previously, it did not exist.

**However, I am finding that the browser file is not being read by the ASP.Net app.**

Do I need to recycle the app pool of the ASP.Net app or restart the app? I am using ASP.Net 4.0.

**UPDATE:** I just discovered that the ASP.Net app is now reading the 'BrowserFile.browser', and so I think, that app pool recycle or app restart is needed for the browser file changes to take effect.

That, I believe is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App pool recycle or app restart is required for browser file changes under App_Browsers folder, to take effect in an ASP.Net app.